# Timezone offset changes in django/postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

I'm having an issue with Django changing the UTC offset of my data, not entirely at random, but with no prompting that I can see.

When I observe it as a `datetime.datetime` object before saving (via `Model.objects.Create()`): `2017-12-29 05:16:00-08:00`

When I check the column manually in Postgres: `2017-12-29 06:32:00-07` (the `-07` offset corresponds to my local timezone)

When I re-load the object in Django: `2017-12-29 13:16:00+00:00`

How can I get it to preserve the original UTC offset? Do I need to save it in a different way?

Comment: Do you have `DateTime(timezone=True)` in the model?

Comment: Is that a parameter for `DateTimeField`? I can't find anything in the django documentation about a parameter like that.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought it was SQLAlchemy.